# how to get currently selected application package name in android programmatically?

Tags: android, sendmessage, ime, android-package-managers, custom-keyboard

I have created custom soft keyboard with images and my task is want to send selected image to the currently selected Application by the user like google hangout but i can get Installed application package name and icon using Package Manager like that if am using google hangout application means i have to get google hangout application package name and from my custom keyboard i have to share selected images directly to the hangout chat conversation as a message how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the installed package details.

```
 public ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> getInstalledApps(Activity mActivity) {
    ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = mActivity.getPackageManager()
            .getInstalledPackages(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        PackageInfoStruct newInfo = new PackageInfoStruct();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(
                mActivity.getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.datadir = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(mActivity
                .getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res;
}

public class PackageInfoStruct {
    String appname = "";
    String pname = "";
    String versionName = "";
    int versionCode = 0;
    Drawable icon;
    String datadir = "";
}
```

Call  `getInstalledApps`

```
ArrayList<PackageInfoStruct> installedPackageDetails = getInstalledApps(getActivity());
```

You can use above method to display list of installed app and on selected you can details from as per selected item. `PackageInfoStruct` class contains details for package

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

Answer (score 1):

From activity 
`String appPackage = currentContext.getPackageName();`

or

```
String appPackage = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

Comment: thanks i found solution for that using this code  ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfos.get(0).topActivity;
                        String currentpackagename = componentInfo.getPackageName();
                        Log.d("currentpackagename : ","#############"+currentpackagename);

Comment: @MahaJeyaraj i too  had the same requirement as of yours, but the above you have  mentioned always return android.app.launcher package